# bootbox type checkbox: just one option selected validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I would like to validate in my bootbox that just one option has selected, like radioButtons, do you have any idea?

This is the code

```
bootbox.prompt({
  title: "Seleccione el autorizado",
  inputType: 'checkbox',
  inputOptions: jsonArray,
  callback: function (result) {
    if(result != null){
      var i = parseInt(result);
      $("#dni").val(data[i].dni);
      $("#nombre").val(data[i].nombre);
      $("#apellido").val(data[i].apellido);
      $("#patente").val(data[i].patente);
      $("#lote").val(data[i].lote);
      $( "#dni, #nombre, #apellido, #patente" ).prop( "disabled", true );
      self.id_ingreso = data[i].id;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you using radio buttons?

Comment: @user2867288 Bootbox doesn't provide radiobuttons as an [input option](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/blob/master/bootbox.js#L55) for the `prompt` function.

Comment: Sure it does.  The radio buttons should be part of the message, not the buttons.

Comment: @RobertMcKee If the user is using the `dialog` function, they can add whatever they want. `prompt` doesn't allow a `message` option, and using the `title` option would just stick the radiobuttons in the header.

Comment: Yes, he would have to switch to using a dialog instead of a prompt to put the radio buttons into the message area.  Although, if it was me, looking at bootbox source, I'd just modify the prompt to accept radio as an option.  Looks like about 10 lines of code to change.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely trivial example, but you can basically check the length of the selected inputs when the user clicks "OK":

https://jsfiddle.net/tc2jpzop/

```
bootbox.prompt({
  title: "This is a prompt with a set of checkbox inputs!",
  inputType: 'checkbox',
  inputOptions: [{
    text: 'Choice One',
    value: '1',
  }, {
    text: 'Choice Two',
    value: '2',
  }, {
    text: 'Choice Three',
    value: '3',
  }],
  callback: function(result) {
    if (result != null) {
      if (result.length > 1) {
        alert("Please select only one option");
        return false;
      } else {
        // do something
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Otherwise, you can add your own listeners to the input elements when the dialog is shown, and add your own "radio" behavior:

```
var dialog = bootbox.prompt({ /* your options */ })

dialog.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    dialog.find('.modal-body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
        /* uncheck other checkboxes when this input is checked */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer @Robert McKee's answer, but as a quicker fix, if you are using JQuery, two more lines of code will make @Tieson T.'s answer fully work:

```
   var dialog = bootbox.prompt({ /* your options */ });

   dialog.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     dialog.find('.modal-body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
       $(dialog).find(":checkbox").map(function(){this.checked = false})
       e.currentTarget.checked = true
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix bootbox:

```
/**
 * bootbox.js [master branch]
 *
 * http://bootboxjs.com/license.txt
 */

// @see https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/180
// @see https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/186
(function (root, factory) {

  "use strict";
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(["jquery"], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.

    if (typeof $ === "undefined") {
      module.exports = factory(require("jquery"));
    } else {
      module.exports = factory($); // jshint ignore:line
    }

  } else {
    // Browser globals (root is window)
    root.bootbox = factory(root.jQuery);
  }

}(this, function init($, undefined) {

  "use strict";

  // the base DOM structure needed to create a modal
  var templates = {
    dialog:
      "<div class='bootbox modal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-hidden='true'>" +
        "<div class='modal-dialog'>" +
          "<div class='modal-content'>" +
            "<div class='modal-body'><div class='bootbox-body'></div></div>" +
          "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
      "</div>",
    header:
      "<div class='modal-header'>" +
        "<h4 class='modal-title'></h4>" +
      "</div>",
    footer:
      "<div class='modal-footer'></div>",
    closeButton:
      "<button type='button' class='bootbox-close-button close' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>",
    form:
      "<form class='bootbox-form'></form>",
    inputs: {
      text:
        "<input class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-text form-control' autocomplete=off type=text />",
      textarea:
        "<textarea class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-textarea form-control'></textarea>",
      email:
        "<input class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-email form-control' autocomplete='off' type='email' />",
      select:
        "<select class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-select form-control'></select>",
      checkbox:
        "<div class='checkbox'><label><input class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-checkbox' type='checkbox' /></label></div>",
      radio:
        "<div class='radio'><label><input class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-checkbox' type='radio' name='bootbox-radio' /></label></div>",      
      date:
        "<input class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-date form-control' autocomplete=off type='date' />",
      time:
        "<input class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-time form-control' autocomplete=off type='time' />",
      number:
        "<input class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-number form-control' autocomplete=off type='number' />",
      password:
        "<input class='bootbox-input bootbox-input-password form-control' autocomplete='off' type='password' />"
    }
  };

  var defaults = {
    // default language
    locale: "en",
    // show backdrop or not. Default to static so user has to interact with dialog
    backdrop: "static",
    // animate the modal in/out
    animate: true,
    // additional class string applied to the top level dialog
    className: null,
    // whether or not to include a close button
    closeButton: true,
    // show the dialog immediately by default
    show: true,
    // dialog container
    container: "body"
  };

  // our public object; augmented after our private API
  var exports = {};

  /**
   * @private
   */
  function _t(key) {
    var locale = locales[defaults.locale];
    return locale ? locale[key] : locales.en[key];
  }

  function processCallback(e, dialog, callback) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // by default we assume a callback will get rid of the dialog,
    // although it is given the opportunity to override this

    // so, if the callback can be invoked and it *explicitly returns false*
    // then we'll set a flag to keep the dialog active...
    var preserveDialog = $.isFunction(callback) && callback.call(dialog, e) === false;

    // ... otherwise we'll bin it
    if (!preserveDialog) {
      dialog.modal("hide");
    }
  }

  // Bootstrap 3.x supports back to IE8 on Windows (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)
  // so unfortunately we can't just get away with assuming Object.keys exists
  function getKeyLength(obj) {
    if (Object.keys) {
      return Object.keys(obj).length;
    }

    var k, t = 0;
    for (k in obj) {
      t ++;
    }
    return t;
  }

  // tiny wrapper function around jQuery.each; just adds index as the third parameter
  function each(collection, iterator) {
    var index = 0;
    $.each(collection, function(key, value) {
      iterator(key, value, index++);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Filter and tidy up any user supplied parameters to this dialog.
   * Also looks for any shorthands used and ensures that the options
   * which are returned are all normalized properly
   */
  function sanitize(options) {
    var buttons;
    var total;

    if (typeof options !== "object") {
      throw new Error("Please supply an object of options");
    }

    if (!options.message) {
      throw new Error("Please specify a message");
    }

    // make sure any supplied options take precedence over defaults
    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    // no buttons is still a valid dialog but it's cleaner  toalways have
    // a buttons object to iterate over, even if it's empty
    if (!options.buttons) {
      options.buttons = {};
    }

    buttons = options.buttons;

    total = getKeyLength(buttons);

    each(buttons, function(key, button, index) {
      var isLast = index === total-1;

      if ($.isFunction(button)) {
        // short form, assume value is our callback. Since button
        // isn't an object it isn't a reference either so re-assign it
        button = buttons[key] = {
          callback: button
        };
      }

      // before any further checks make sure by now button is the correct type
      if ($.type(button) !== "object") {
        throw new Error("button with key " + key + " must be an object");
      }

      if (!button.label) {
        // the lack of an explicit label means we'll assume the key is good enough
        button.label = key;
      }

      if (!button.className) {
        if (total <= 2 && isLast) {
          // always add a primary to the main option in a one or two-button dialog
          button.className = "btn-primary";
        } else {
          button.className = "btn-default";
        }
      }
    });

    return options;
  }

  /**
   * map a flexible set of arguments into a single returned object
   * if args.length is already one just return it, otherwise
   * use the properties argument to map the unnamed args to
   * object properties
   * so in the latter case:
   * mapArguments(["foo", $.noop], ["message", "callback"])
   * -> { message: "foo", callback: $.noop }
   */
  function mapArguments(args, properties) {
    var argn = args.length;
    var options = {};

    if (argn < 1 || argn > 2) {
      throw new Error("Invalid argument length");
    }

    if (argn === 2 || typeof args[0] === "string") {
      options[properties[0]] = args[0];
      options[properties[1]] = args[1];
    } else {
      options = args[0];
    }

    return options;
  }

  /**
   * merge a set of default dialog options with user supplied arguments
   */
  function mergeArguments(defaults, args, properties) {
    return $.extend(
      // deep merge
      true,
      // ensure the target is an empty, unreferenced object
      {},
      // the base options object for this type of dialog (often just buttons)
      defaults,
      // args could be an object or array; if it's an array properties will
      // map it to a proper options object
      mapArguments(
        args,
        properties
      )
    );
  }

  /**
   * this entry-level method makes heavy use of composition to take a simple
   * range of inputs and return valid options suitable for passing to bootbox.dialog
   */
  function mergeDialogOptions(className, labels, properties, args) {
    //  build up a base set of dialog properties
    var baseOptions = {
      className: "bootbox-" + className,
      buttons: createLabels.apply(null, labels)
    };

    // ensure the buttons properties generated, *after* merging
    // with user args are still valid against the supplied labels
    return validateButtons(
      // merge the generated base properties with user supplied arguments
      mergeArguments(
        baseOptions,
        args,
        // if args.length > 1, properties specify how each arg maps to an object key
        properties
      ),
      labels
    );
  }

  /**
   * from a given list of arguments return a suitable object of button labels
   * all this does is normalise the given labels and translate them where possible
   * e.g. "ok", "confirm" -> { ok: "OK", cancel: "Annuleren" }
   */
  function createLabels() {
    var buttons = {};

    for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
      var argument = arguments[i];
      var key = argument.toLowerCase();
      var value = argument.toUpperCase();

      buttons[key] = {
        label: _t(value)
      };
    }

    return buttons;
  }

  function validateButtons(options, buttons) {
    var allowedButtons = {};
    each(buttons, function(key, value) {
      allowedButtons[value] = true;
    });

    each(options.buttons, function(key) {
      if (allowedButtons[key] === undefined) {
        throw new Error("button key " + key + " is not allowed (options are " + buttons.join("\n") + ")");
      }
    });

    return options;
  }

  exports.alert = function() {
    var options;

    options = mergeDialogOptions("alert", ["ok"], ["message", "callback"], arguments);

    // @TODO: can this move inside exports.dialog when we're iterating over each
    // button and checking its button.callback value instead?
    if (options.callback && !$.isFunction(options.callback)) {
      throw new Error("alert requires callback property to be a function when provided");
    }

    /**
     * override the ok and escape callback to make sure they just invoke
     * the single user-supplied one (if provided)
     */
    options.buttons.ok.callback = options.onEscape = function() {
      if ($.isFunction(options.callback)) {
        return options.callback.call(this);
      }
      return true;
    };

    return exports.dialog(options);
  };

  exports.confirm = function() {
    var options;

    options = mergeDialogOptions("confirm", ["cancel", "confirm"], ["message", "callback"], arguments);

    // confirm specific validation; they don't make sense without a callback so make
    // sure it's present
    if (!$.isFunction(options.callback)) {
      throw new Error("confirm requires a callback");
    }

    /**
     * overrides; undo anything the user tried to set they shouldn't have
     */
    options.buttons.cancel.callback = options.onEscape = function() {
      return options.callback.call(this, false);
    };

    options.buttons.confirm.callback = function() {
      return options.callback.call(this, true);
    };

    return exports.dialog(options);
  };

  exports.prompt = function() {
    var options;
    var defaults;
    var dialog;
    var form;
    var input;
    var shouldShow;
    var inputOptions;

    // we have to create our form first otherwise
    // its value is undefined when gearing up our options
    // @TODO this could be solved by allowing message to
    // be a function instead...
    form = $(templates.form);

    // prompt defaults are more complex than others in that
    // users can override more defaults
    // @TODO I don't like that prompt has to do a lot of heavy
    // lifting which mergeDialogOptions can *almost* support already
    // just because of 'value' and 'inputType' - can we refactor?
    defaults = {
      className: "bootbox-prompt",
      buttons: createLabels("cancel", "confirm"),
      value: "",
      inputType: "text"
    };

    options = validateButtons(
      mergeArguments(defaults, arguments, ["title", "callback"]),
      ["cancel", "confirm"]
    );

    // capture the user's show value; we always set this to false before
    // spawning the dialog to give us a chance to attach some handlers to
    // it, but we need to make sure we respect a preference not to show it
    shouldShow = (options.show === undefined) ? true : options.show;

    /**
     * overrides; undo anything the user tried to set they shouldn't have
     */
    options.message = form;

    options.buttons.cancel.callback = options.onEscape = function() {
      return options.callback.call(this, null);
    };

    options.buttons.confirm.callback = function() {
      var value;

      if (options.inputType === "checkbox" || options.inputType==="radio") {
        value = input.find("input:checked").map(function() {
          return $(this).val();
        }).get();
      } else {
        value = input.val();
      }

      return options.callback.call(this, value);
    };

    options.show = false;

    // prompt specific validation
    if (!options.title) {
      throw new Error("prompt requires a title");
    }

    if (!$.isFunction(options.callback)) {
      throw new Error("prompt requires a callback");
    }

    if (!templates.inputs[options.inputType]) {
      throw new Error("invalid prompt type");
    }

    // create the input based on the supplied type
    input = $(templates.inputs[options.inputType]);

    switch (options.inputType) {
      case "text":
      case "textarea":
      case "email":
      case "date":
      case "time":
      case "number":
      case "password":
        input.val(options.value);
        break;

      case "select":
        var groups = {};
        inputOptions = options.inputOptions || [];

        if (!$.isArray(inputOptions)) {
          throw new Error("Please pass an array of input options");
        }

        if (!inputOptions.length) {
          throw new Error("prompt with select requires options");
        }

        each(inputOptions, function(_, option) {

          // assume the element to attach to is the input...
          var elem = input;

          if (option.value === undefined || option.text === undefined) {
            throw new Error("each option needs a `value` and a `text` property");
          }

          // ... but override that element if this option sits in a group

          if (option.group) {
            // initialise group if necessary
            if (!groups[option.group]) {
              groups[option.group] = $("<optgroup/>").attr("label", option.group);
            }

            elem = groups[option.group];
          }

          elem.append("<option value='" + option.value + "'>" + option.text + "</option>");
        });

        each(groups, function(_, group) {
          input.append(group);
        });

        // safe to set a select's value as per a normal input
        input.val(options.value);
        break;

      case "checkbox":
      case "radio":
        var values   = $.isArray(options.value) ? options.value : [options.value];
        inputOptions = options.inputOptions || [];

        if (!inputOptions.length) {
          throw new Error("prompt with checkbox requires options");
        }

        if (!inputOptions[0].value || !inputOptions[0].text) {
          throw new Error("each option needs a `value` and a `text` property");
        }

        // checkboxes have to nest within a containing element, so
        // they break the rules a bit and we end up re-assigning
        // our 'input' element to this container instead
        input = $("<div/>");

        each(inputOptions, function(_, option) {
          var checkbox = $(templates.inputs[options.inputType]);

          checkbox.find("input").attr("value", option.value);
          checkbox.find("label").append(option.text);

          // we've ensured values is an array so we can always iterate over it
          each(values, function(_, value) {
            if (value === option.value) {
              checkbox.find("input").prop("checked", true);
            }
          });

          input.append(checkbox);
        });
        break;
    }

    // @TODO provide an attributes option instead
    // and simply map that as keys: vals
    if (options.placeholder) {
      input.attr("placeholder", options.placeholder);
    }

    if (options.pattern) {
      input.attr("pattern", options.pattern);
    }

    if (options.maxlength) {
      input.attr("maxlength", options.maxlength);
    }

    // now place it in our form
    form.append(input);

    form.on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Fix for SammyJS (or similar JS routing library) hijacking the form post.
      e.stopPropagation();
      // @TODO can we actually click *the* button object instead?
      // e.g. buttons.confirm.click() or similar
      dialog.find(".btn-primary").click();
    });

    dialog = exports.dialog(options);

    // clear the existing handler focusing the submit button...
    dialog.off("shown.bs.modal");

    // ...and replace it with one focusing our input, if possible
    dialog.on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
      // need the closure here since input isn't
      // an object otherwise
      input.focus();
    });

    if (shouldShow === true) {
      dialog.modal("show");
    }

    return dialog;
  };

  exports.dialog = function(options) {
    options = sanitize(options);

    var dialog = $(templates.dialog);
    var innerDialog = dialog.find(".modal-dialog");
    var body = dialog.find(".modal-body");
    var buttons = options.buttons;
    var buttonStr = "";
    var callbacks = {
      onEscape: options.onEscape
    };

    if ($.fn.modal === undefined) {
      throw new Error(
        "$.fn.modal is not defined; please double check you have included " +
        "the Bootstrap JavaScript library. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ " +
        "for more details."
      );
    }

    each(buttons, function(key, button) {

      // @TODO I don't like this string appending to itself; bit dirty. Needs reworking
      // can we just build up button elements instead? slower but neater. Then button
      // can just become a template too
      buttonStr += "<button data-bb-handler='" + key + "' type='button' class='btn " + button.className + "'>" + button.label + "</button>";
      callbacks[key] = button.callback;
    });

    body.find(".bootbox-body").html(options.message);

    if (options.animate === true) {
      dialog.addClass("fade");
    }

    if (options.className) {
      dialog.addClass(options.className);
    }

    if (options.size === "large") {
      innerDialog.addClass("modal-lg");
    } else if (options.size === "small") {
      innerDialog.addClass("modal-sm");
    }

    if (options.title) {
      body.before(templates.header);
    }

    if (options.closeButton) {
      var closeButton = $(templates.closeButton);

      if (options.title) {
        dialog.find(".modal-header").prepend(closeButton);
      } else {
        closeButton.css("margin-top", "-2px").prependTo(body);
      }
    }

    if (options.title) {
      dialog.find(".modal-title").html(options.title);
    }

    if (buttonStr.length) {
      body.after(templates.footer);
      dialog.find(".modal-footer").html(buttonStr);
    }


    /**
     * Bootstrap event listeners; these handle extra
     * setup & teardown required after the underlying
     * modal has performed certain actions
     */

    // make sure we unbind any listeners once the dialog has definitively been dismissed
    dialog.one("hide.bs.modal", function() {
      dialog.off("escape.close.bb");
      dialog.off("click");
    });

    dialog.one("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
      // ensure we don't accidentally intercept hidden events triggered
      // by children of the current dialog. We shouldn't anymore now BS
      // namespaces its events; but still worth doing
      if (e.target === this) {
        dialog.remove();
      }
    });

    /*
    dialog.on("show.bs.modal", function() {
      // sadly this doesn't work; show is called *just* before
      // the backdrop is added so we'd need a setTimeout hack or
      // otherwise... leaving in as would be nice
      if (options.backdrop) {
        dialog.next(".modal-backdrop").addClass("bootbox-backdrop");
      }
    });
    */

    dialog.one("shown.bs.modal", function() {
      dialog.find(".btn-primary:first").focus();
    });

    /**
     * Bootbox event listeners; used to decouple some
     * behaviours from their respective triggers
     */

    if (options.backdrop !== "static") {
      // A boolean true/false according to the Bootstrap docs
      // should show a dialog the user can dismiss by clicking on
      // the background.
      // We always only ever pass static/false to the actual
      // $.modal function because with `true` we can't trap
      // this event (the .modal-backdrop swallows it)
      // However, we still want to sort of respect true
      // and invoke the escape mechanism instead
      dialog.on("click.dismiss.bs.modal", function(e) {
        // @NOTE: the target varies in >= 3.3.x releases since the modal backdrop
        // moved *inside* the outer dialog rather than *alongside* it
        if (dialog.children(".modal-backdrop").length) {
          e.currentTarget = dialog.children(".modal-backdrop").get(0);
        }

        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
          return;
        }

        dialog.trigger("escape.close.bb");
      });
    }

    dialog.on("escape.close.bb", function(e) {
      // the if statement looks redundant but it isn't; without it
      // if we *didn't* have an onEscape handler then processCallback
      // would automatically dismiss the dialog
      if (callbacks.onEscape) {
        processCallback(e, dialog, callbacks.onEscape);
      }
    });

    /**
     * Standard jQuery event listeners; used to handle user
     * interaction with our dialog
     */

    dialog.on("click", ".modal-footer button", function(e) {
      var callbackKey = $(this).data("bb-handler");

      processCallback(e, dialog, callbacks[callbackKey]);
    });

    dialog.on("click", ".bootbox-close-button", function(e) {
      // onEscape might be falsy but that's fine; the fact is
      // if the user has managed to click the close button we
      // have to close the dialog, callback or not
      processCallback(e, dialog, callbacks.onEscape);
    });

    dialog.on("keyup", function(e) {
      if (e.which === 27) {
        dialog.trigger("escape.close.bb");
      }
    });

    // the remainder of this method simply deals with adding our
    // dialogent to the DOM, augmenting it with Bootstrap's modal
    // functionality and then giving the resulting object back
    // to our caller

    $(options.container).append(dialog);

    dialog.modal({
      backdrop: options.backdrop ? "static": false,
      keyboard: false,
      show: false
    });

    if (options.show) {
      dialog.modal("show");
    }

    // @TODO should we return the raw element here or should
    // we wrap it in an object on which we can expose some neater
    // methods, e.g. var d = bootbox.alert(); d.hide(); instead
    // of d.modal("hide");

   /*
    function BBDialog(elem) {
      this.elem = elem;
    }

    BBDialog.prototype = {
      hide: function() {
        return this.elem.modal("hide");
      },
      show: function() {
        return this.elem.modal("show");
      }
    };
    */

    return dialog;

  };

  exports.setDefaults = function() {
    var values = {};

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
      // allow passing of single key/value...
      values[arguments[0]] = arguments[1];
    } else {
      // ... and as an object too
      values = arguments[0];
    }

    $.extend(defaults, values);
  };

  exports.hideAll = function() {
    $(".bootbox").modal("hide");

    return exports;
  };


  /**
   * standard locales. Please add more according to ISO 639-1 standard. Multiple language variants are
   * unlikely to be required. If this gets too large it can be split out into separate JS files.
   */
  var locales = {
    en : {
      OK      : "OK",
      CANCEL  : "Cancel",
      CONFIRM : "OK"
    }
  };

  exports.addLocale = function(name, values) {
    $.each(["OK", "CANCEL", "CONFIRM"], function(_, v) {
      if (!values[v]) {
        throw new Error("Please supply a translation for '" + v + "'");
      }
    });

    locales[name] = {
      OK: values.OK,
      CANCEL: values.CANCEL,
      CONFIRM: values.CONFIRM
    };

    return exports;
  };

  exports.removeLocale = function(name) {
    delete locales[name];

    return exports;
  };

  exports.setLocale = function(name) {
    return exports.setDefaults("locale", name);
  };

  exports.init = function(_$) {
    return init(_$ || $);
  };

  return exports;
}));
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var jsonArray =  [{
    "text": "One",
    "value": 1
 }, {
    "text": "Two",
    "value": 2
 }, {
    "text": "Three",
    "value": 3
 }];

bootbox.prompt({
  title: "Seleccione el autorizado",
  inputType: 'radio',
  inputOptions: jsonArray,
  callback: function (result) {
    if(result != null){
      console.log($('input[name="bootbox-radio"]:checked').val());
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that I had to strip out the non-english locales from my custom bootbox because the message was too long, but the full original is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQpLRP

Comment: Feel free to post this to bootbox as a PR for radio support, although it probably should be cleaned up to return a single value instead of an array.